# Time without timezone error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i've got an error with my rake task, I'm trying to simplify the rake task. This is the row i've getting stuck on

```
  events = Event.where('eventname ILIKE ? AND time ILIKE ? AND date = ?', "%#{row.product_name}%", "%#{row.delivery_time}%", "%#{row.valid_from}%")
```

(if i remove time and delivery time it runs fine)

However if i run it with this it gets stuck on this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone ~~* unknown
LINE 1: ...LIKE '%Portsmouth Guildhall Membership%' AND time ILIKE '%23...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (eventname ILIKE '%Portsmouth Guildhall Membership%' AND time ILIKE '%23:00:00%' AND date = '%2016-12-31%')
```

Any ideas would be great, Just for further clarification, The time is coming out of the events table as this:

```
18:00:00
```

And the table type is a time field

Sam

Comment: Why you want to use ILIKE on time field and why not just `time =?`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is occurring because you need to explicitly convert the timestamp to a string before using a string operation on it. eg:

```
select * from course_statuses where updated_at ILIKE '%13:24:51%'
```

Above one will give me error but after typecasting updated_at to updated_at::text no error will come:

```
select * from course_statuses where updated_at::text ILIKE '%13:24:51%'
```

try it on pgadmin3